# Solidity Function Signature - question about part of signature

Tags: methods, ethereum, solidity, signature, smartcontracts

I'm looking at examples of Smart Contracts written in Solidity and I found a constructor with the signature:

```
constructor() ERC721Full("<Token name>", "<Token Symbol>") public {

}
```

what is the **ERC721Full("", "")** part of the signature? And how am I able to pass arguments into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hardcode it, or modify your constructor to have more parameters.

Code example:

```
contract A {
    string public name;
    constructor(string tokenName) public {
        name = tokenName;
    }
}

// Hardcode
contract B is A {
    constructor() A("My tokenName") public {

    }
}

// Add params to constructor
contract C is A {
    constructor(string tokenName) A(tokenName) public {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found answer here:
https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#arguments-for-base-constructors

You can pass arguments to parent's constructors through a child constructor's "modifier"